# Dynamic queries in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Using TSQL stored procedures, dynamic queries were a cinch. For example, say I had a reporting application that optionally asked for archived records. The stored procedure would look like so:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @join nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @where nvarchar(MAX)

IF @optionalvar1 IS NOT NULL
    SET @where = COALESCE(@where, '') +
    'AND SomeColumn = ' + @optionalvar1 + ' '

IF @optionalvar2 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @join = COALESCE(@join, '') +
   'LEFT JOIN SomeTable s 
    ON st.Column = s.Column '

    SET @where = COALESCE(@where, '') +
    'AND s.SomeColumn = ' + @optionalvar2 + ' '
    END

SET @sql =
'
SELECT
    *
FROM
    StaticTable st
    ' + COALESCE(@join, '') + '
WHERE
    1=1
    ' + COALESCE(@where, '') + '
'
```

Barring any silly typos, that's how I've done dynamic queries before. For each new optional parameter I add another conditional block and add the necessary join and where code (and adapt the model if I need to also add ordering, etc.). I'm trying to work out how to do this in Entities but am having a rough time of it.

Most links I've found (http://naspinski.net/post/Writing-Dynamic-Linq-Queries-in-Linq-to-Entities.aspx in particular) show how to look for a dynamically changing string using this bit of code:

```
var data = ctx.table.Where(b => b.branch_id == 5 || b.display == "Hello");
```

I don't think this works in my example, as I need to dynamically add n-number of additional where clauses and possibly joins depending on what variables are passed in.

I had hoped I could do something simple like:

```
    var query =
        (from t in ctx.Table
         select t);

    if (optionalvar1)
    {
        query = query.Join('etc');
        query = query.Where('etc');
    }
```

But didn't make much progress (can't quite figure out the syntax of either to get them to do what I want.

Any ideas? Am I approaching this wrong? Is there a better, simpler solution? I know at the end of the day I could always have a slew of conditionals checking for each possible set of combinations, then generating the entire LINQ query within that block, but the amount of copy-pasta required there is frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're not using the *result* of the `Where` clause. Just calling `Where` and ignoring the return value won't change what's in `query` at all. With the joins it could be somewhat tricky, but without them it's easy:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Text == "Some value");
}
```

If you can give more information about what your joins need to do, we can probably sort that out too.

Note that as far as I can see, your dynamic SQL version would have been vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, btw - something which isn't the case using LINQ.

Comment: Sorry, failing to set query = query.Where was more of a typo than anything. My main issue is how to express my query inside the .Where bit. I can't work with just the object 'x' - that's a POCO containing the end-result of my query. What I need to do in most cases, however, is add a where clause on other tables involved in the query, but not necessarily returned in the end-object. I'll update the question to clarify. (Also, the variables passed into the dynamic SQL originate from parameterized queries in .NET and get excuted with sp_executesql - should be ok(?).)

Comment: @rake: It *looks* like it's just a POCO, but LINQ to Entities will actually be converting them into SQL. The bit about requiring things not present in the rest of the query is hard to talk about without a concrete example. And no, I don't believe that your dynamic SQL is safe from SQL injection attacks just because they're parameterized in .NET. The value of each parameter is being inserted directly into the final SQL. I strongly suggest you try it. Just a query which includes a single quote should be enough to give you an idea of what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right actually. remember that the sql will be generated and executed when you request the data.

you can do something like

```
var v = (from p in Context.User select p);

if (txtLastName.Text.Lenght > 0)
{
    v = (from p in v where p.LastName.Contains(txtLastName.Text) select p);
}

if (txtCity.Text.Lenght > 0)
{
    v = (from p in v
         join q in Context.City on p.City equals q.CityId
         where q.CityName.Contains(txtCity.Text) select p);
}
```